# Print just the specific word from a list, no other word included

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi thanks for reading my question. I am using Python 2.7 on windows 7. As a newbie, I have a question regarding how to print out the line number with specific word from a list.

Firstly, the list is:

```
MainBoard Serial Number,OPS40217,8030dc8edca9,
MainBoard Version,4,,
Model,BoVaConnected,905-0321,
Nucleo URL, nucleo.cloud.com
QAState,QA_STATE_APPROVED
Serial Number,OPS40217,8030dc8edca9,P
```

From the list, you can see there are two 'Serial Number' (first and last line). But I would to extract the last line number which includes the keyword 'Serial Number' only, not including other words.

My current code is:

```
lines = list.split('\n')
SN = 'Serial Number'
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if SN in line:  # or word in line.split() to search for full words
        sn = i + 1
        print sn
```

From my code, the printout is with two line numbers (the first and last line numbers). So is there any way to just index the specific keyword line number? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split each line on commas, and then check to see whether your target phrase is in the list of phrases on each line.

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if SN in line.split(','):  # or word in line.split() to search for full words
        print i + 1
```

Will that do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a list?

```
container = [ ]
SN = 'Serial Number'
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if SN in line:
        sn = i + 1
        container.append( 'sn' )

print container[container.length() - 1]
```